# use another list items in IN query in existing left join linq query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

```
dynamic memberEomMapping;
                using (var context = new MIHR.Business.EF.SA_MIHR_DEVEntities())
                {
                    memberEomMapping = (from c in context.MemberEomMapping
                                        join
                                            b in context.EntityOrgModule on c.EomId equals b.Id 
                                        where c.MemberPersonId == PersonId &&  b.EOMTYPEID == 116001
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            c.EomId,
                                            b.Name
                                        }).ToList();

                }
```

I have this list which returns me a list of EomId and Name , Now next to this query i have another query in which i want to get the list of items which are in this list ( in short use this query result as in query for another list )

here is code for another list

```
dynamic entityOrgModule;
                using (var context = new MIHR.Business.EF.SA_MIHR_DEVEntities())
                {

                    entityOrgModule = (from c in context.EntityOrgModule
                                       join p in context.MemberEomMapping on c.Id equals p.EomId into gj
                                       from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                       where c.EntityType == UserEntityTypeId && c.EntityId == UserEntityId && c.Rowstatus == 1 && c.EOMTYPEID == 116002 && (c.ParentId==2 || c.ParentId==3)
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           c.Id,
                                           c.Name,
                                           c.ParentId,
                                           isSelected = (x == null ? false : true)
                                       }).ToList();

                }
```

so in this above query instead of `(c.ParentId==2 || c.ParentId==3)` this criteria should be use from `memberEomMapping` list.

I have tried something like this

```
dynamic entityOrgModule;
                using (var context = new MIHR.Business.EF.SA_MIHR_DEVEntities())
                {

                    entityOrgModule = (from c in context.EntityOrgModule
                                       join p in context.MemberEomMapping on c.Id equals p.EomId into gj
                                       from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                       where c.EntityType == UserEntityTypeId && c.EntityId == UserEntityId && c.Rowstatus == 1 && c.EOMTYPEID == 116002 && memberEomMapping.Contains(c.ParentId) 
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           c.Id,
                                           c.Name,
                                           c.ParentId,
                                           isSelected = (x == null ? false : true)
                                       }).ToList();

                }
```

but this give me another compile time error

**An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Use .Any()

**Edit:**

Replace `dynamic memberEomMapping;`

with

`var memberEomMapping = new[]{new { EomId = 0, Name = "" }}.ToList();`

And

```
List<int> mylist = memberEomMapping.Select(x => x.EomId).ToList();
```

Then

```
dynamic entityOrgModule;
            using (var context = new MIHR.Business.EF.SA_MIHR_DEVEntities())
            {

                entityOrgModule = (from c in context.EntityOrgModule
                                   join p in context.MemberEomMapping on c.Id equals p.EomId into gj
                                   from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   where c.EntityType == UserEntityTypeId && c.EntityId == UserEntityId && c.Rowstatus == 1 && c.EOMTYPEID == 116002 && mylist.Any(y => y == c.ParentId) 
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       c.Id,
                                       c.Name,
                                       c.ParentId,
                                       isSelected = (x == null ? false : true)
                                   }).ToList();

            }
```

Comment: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: Replace dynamic memberEomMapping; with var memberEomMapping = new[]{new { EomId = 0, Name = "" }}.ToList();